# eShopOnContainers in docker on Portainer, envoy Error initializing configuration '/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml': Invalid path: /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml

Tags: .net, docker, envoyproxy, portainer

I have an eShopOnContainers project that I have successfully deployed to a portainer.io (v2.9.0) instance by creating a stack with the git Repository integration.
All of the containers/images in the stack have started and are running successfully except for the envoyproxy/envoy:v1.11.1 Images and associated containers (mobileshoppingapigw & webshoppingapigw)

The error that I am receiving in the logs is
[critical][main] [source/server/server.cc:93] error initializing configuration '/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml': Invalid path: /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml

Since the docker won't start, I did complete a detached mode, blocking the full start, from the terminal using

`docker run -d --entrypoint sleep envoyproxy/envoy:v1.11.1 3600`

Which then allowed me to confirm that the file path exists and the file has the appropriate permissions

```
  docker exec -it {ID} ls -l /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1430 Aug 13  2019 /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
```